# Python urlencode won't encode values with arrays

Tags: php, python, arrays

I am using the following to create post variables in my PHP file:

```
test=urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('php.php',urllib.urlencode({'test':[1,2,3,4,5]}))).read()
print test
```

I would like it to create a `$_POST` in the `php.php` file that is an array of variables and arrays.

php.php:

```
print_r($_POST['test']);
echo is_array($_POST['test'])?"YES! THIS IS AN ARRAY":"NO! THIS IS A STRING";
```

Unfortunately, the farthest it will go is to create a 'string' representation of an array.

[image]

I have tried setting `urlencode` param to `True` like so from suggestions I saw in similar questions:

```
urlencode({'test':[1,2,3,4,5]},True)
```

[image]

I also tried to use Python `requests.post` and got similar results.

But as you can see, it only outputs the last number from the array. Is there a way to fix this within the Python script?

Comment: Is it okay to parse the string you get into an array in your php file?

Comment: I can advise how to have a string representation of an array in PHP, and how to turn it back into an array in PHP. Can't help you with Python.

Comment: Alright thanks!, I also tried to use Python requests.post and got similar results. I was just looking for an answer from the Python side of things. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and it was quite simple.

Just change the `{'test':[1,2,3,4,5]}` key to `{'test[]':[1,2,3,4,5]}`

Notice how I added `[]`

And make sure you have `True` in your parameters

```
response=urllib2.urlopen(URL,urllib2.Request(urlencode({'test[]':[1,2,3,4,5]},True)))
```

If you are using requests.post method:

```
response=requests.post(URL,data={'test[]':[1,2,3,4,5]})
```